# Electron building out the app with electron-packager dev tools auto open

Tags: javascript, electron

So I installed electron packager and have ran then command:

```
electron-packager . --asar
```

After it has built the app out I opened it and the dev tools auto open. How can I build out the app so the dev tools do not auto open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't realize that `mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()` was in my main.js file from the boiler code I started with. I commented that out and built my app out again and that works.